# How to include data files with the app's APK?

Tags: android, file, installation, publishing

I want to create some pre-created files when my Android application is installed.

I would like to create the file in both the internal memory (data/data//files/) and in a newly created sdcard directories (/sdcard//data1/).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can save you files in `\res\raw` and write the code to store this files to the desired locations if it does not exist when the app start.
Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to access the internal memory and sdcard
and access the `raw` file using the following

```
InputStream databaseInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);
```

Answer (score 45):

If you have a larger number of files and a directory structure you should use /assets. These are not given any R-constants and can be scanned by your application

To open an asset-file:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("path/file.ext");
```

To list a directory:

```
String[] files = getAssets().list("");
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. also see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String) and http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning that really large amounts of data can be dealt with [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

In 2016, *Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 100MB. For most applications, this is plenty of space.*

The APK size limit increases from time to time, so it's meaningful to check the current digit.