# Where do I Include file for Drive service account

Tags: android, google-drive-api, android-file

I am trying to use a google Drive service account, integrating with my app. I do not know where to put the XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-privatekey.p12 for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this post is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4310733/1888585

where all I would have to do is include the file in the `/res/raw/` folder and load it in an input stream like so: (if working in an activity)

`InputStream in = getAssets().open("path/to/file.ext");`

or

`InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);`

From there will be figuring out how to use this inputstream to load to google for this file. 
Above, shows what I need to do as an answer the my original question.