# How to install existing file into apk, when it isn't one of the standard resource types?

Tags: android

currently i look for a way to install an odt-file into internal app storage. I thought that a file must be something placeable in resources folder R, **but none of the resource types really fits/ makes sense**.

Can someone please tell me where to look?

Comment: ...\app\src\main\res\raw is the usual place to put it.

Comment: See answers on [How to include data files with the app's APK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310695/how-to-include-data-files-with-the-apps-apk)  [I considered marking this question as a duplicate, but you are asking about a specific type of file, and are unsure due to the resource types not seeming to fit your file; this seems worthy of being explained by someone. So instead I've upvoted, hoping to keep your question around until someone more experienced can explain.]

Comment: .. I've also made the title more specific, and bolded the key phrase that differentiates this question from existing questions.

Comment: Thanks for not putting anger on me! You already helped me