# Java NoSuchFileException When File Exists

Tags: java, android, nosuchfileexception

I am attempting to parse a json file as part of an android development project. Here is the error message that keeps popping up:
`W/System.err: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:/Users/andno/Desktop/AndroidDev2ClimateApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/androiddev2climateapp/ui/home/test.json`
However, in android studios, the path in the error is supplied as a link, which I can click, leading me to the write file- thus, I don't think the path is wrong.
Here is my code:

```
String first = "C:/Users/andno/Desktop/AndroidDev2ClimateApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/androiddev2climateapp/ui/home/test.json";
try {
    String fileContents = new String((Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(first))));
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(fileContents);
    JSONArray widgets = new JSONArray("WidgetArray");
    for(int i = 0; i < widgets.length(); i++){
        int id = widgets.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id");
        System.out.println(id);
    }
} catch(IOException | JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sorry that the formatting is messed up. I have tried using \ in the path instead of / as well, but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated- thanks so much!

Comment: Try printning out the absolute path for your file object .

Comment: Try putting the slashes in the other way? You'll need to double them to escape them in the string, so `"C:\\Users\\"`

Comment: Why would you like to open a file from the Windows file system in an Android project?

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310695/how-to-include-data-files-with-the-apps-apk) is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get this code to work when you're testing, but obviously, there is no `C:\Users\andno` on your android phone and there never will be.

You're barking up the wrong tree. You don't want to read a file at all.

You want to read a resource from the same place java (or, rather, android) is loading the class file (or whatever passes for class file in android). Which is probably from within a jar or apk or whatnot.

`UiMain.class.getResource("test.json")`

or

`UiMain.class.getResourceAsStream("test.json")`

will get you a resource named `test.json` from the same place that `UiMain.class` is located (i.e. in the same package, I'm assuming this is class `com.example.android.androiddev2climateapp.home.ui.UiMain`. The first one as a URL, which you can usually pass to constructors of images and the like, and the second as stream, which you'd need to safely close (try/finally or try-with-resources if android has gotten around to adding that 20 year old java feature already), and which you can turn into a string using various APIs. Probably the JSON API itself can just be fed an inputstream.